# Reformat date in python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I am having the current format date `02/16/18 3:33:39PM`. How could I use python programming to change it for `Year-Month-Day`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime). Convert your date to a `datatime` object and then do whatever you want from there